# Where clause testing where all must match

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I have a table which contains the fields student_number and and a completed flag which its either completed or non completed.

I'm looking to write a where clause which allows me to check select if 3 student numbers and check if they all have completed in their completed field , however all must match .

Any idea how id go about this ?

Comment: Pls provide some sample data and show us what you have tried so for ?

Comment: So say I select the student numbers 34646, 57858 and 48482 . Ive tried doing WHERE STUDENT NUMBER = 34646 OR 57858 OR 48482 AND COMPLETED = 'COMPLETED' . But that doesn't put in the condition that all have to be completed for the statement to be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you want something like that:

```
where STUDENT.NUMBER in (34646, 57858, 48482) and COMPLETED = 'COMPLETED'
```

(based on you comment)

Comment: So does that test that all 3 of those student numbers are completed? I'm going to be using a case function which basically says when all 3 are completed do this else incomplete

Comment: in case funtion this will be: case when STUDENT.NUMBER in (34646, 57858, 48482) and COMPLETED = 'COMPLETED' then DO_SOMETHING else DO_SOMETHING_ELSE end

Answer (score 0):

```
    DROP TABLE T;
    CREATE TABLE T (ID INT, COMPLETED VARCHAR(20))
    INSERT INTO T VALUES
    (34646, 'COMPLETD'),(57858,'COMPLETeD'),(48482,'COMPLETED')

    SELECT case when s.sta > 0 then 'NotAllCompleted'
            else 'AllCompleted'
            end
     FROM   
    (
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN COMPLETED <> 'COMPLETED' AND ID IN(34646,57858,48482) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) sta 
    FROM T
    ) S

---------------
NotAllCompleted

(1 rows affected)

truncate table t
INSERT INTO T VALUES
(34646, 'COMPLETeD'),(57858,'COMPLETeD'),(48482,'COMPLETED')
    SELECT case when s.sta > 0 then 'NotAllCompleted'
            else 'AllCompleted'
            end
     FROM   
    (
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN COMPLETED <> 'COMPLETED' AND ID IN(34646,57858,48482) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) sta 
    FROM T
    ) S
---------------
AllCompleted

(1 rows affected)
```